# Multi-node Hadoop Issue (Connection refused)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, connection

I have installed a multi-node **Hadoop** version *2.4.1*. When I test mapreduce example wordcount, I have a problem.

The map is working fine, but the reduce fails.

The log file says the following:

```
Call From smva01hdnamenode/10.166.140.191 to node002:58087 failed on connection exception:   
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

node002 is associated with the ip address of a data node;
10.166.140.191 is the ip address of the name node.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your firewall blocking the connection to this port? I had the similar problem and i fixed it by allowing connection to the port.

Comment: In order to ask for more information or clarification you should post a comment. Your contribution is not really an answer...

Comment: I dont have reputation of 50 to post a comment. Thats what it said when i tried to do, so i quickly added it as an answer instead of getting into details of why it is saying so.